# WPF: Animating in XAML, rather than C#?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, wpf-controls

.I am creating a user control that stacks three WPF month calendars (Master, Slave1, and Slave2) vertically. I want the second and third calendars to be hidden until the host window is large enough to show the entire month--no partial calendars. I have implemented the feature be trapping the SizeChanged event in an event handler in code-behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows only complete calendars--partially visible calendars are hidden.
/// </summary>
private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Increasing window height
    var newHeight = e.NewSize.Height;
    if (newHeight > 500)
    {
        SlaveCalendar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        SlaveCalendar2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else if (newHeight > 332)
    {
        SlaveCalendar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        SlaveCalendar2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    else
    {
        SlaveCalendar1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        SlaveCalendar2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I would rather implement the feature in XAML, and I am not sure how to do it. Any suggestions? I'm not looking for someone else to write this for me--just point me in the right direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm puzzled about why you marked nportelli's answer as "best", since it actually leads you in a direction that won't work.  The idea Aviad P. gives *will* actually work and is rather elegant.

Comment: Aviad P's solution does not address the question. I already have a code solution that works--I am looking for a XAML solution.

Comment: There's a code-behind solution which is not reusable, and tailored to a specific view, and there's a code solution which is reusable and suitable for any view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with xaml templates and triggers.  Probably event triggers for the OnSizeChanged event.  I believe

Here are some resources to get you pointed in the right direction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294856%28Expression.30%29.aspx
http://www.wpfdude.com/articles/Triggers.aspx
http://www.geektieguy.com/2008/01/05/wpf-controltemplate-trigger-tip/

Comment: The links are interesting, but the answer is incorrect.  Triggers can't solve the problem in pure XAML because they can't do numeric comparisons.  See Aviad P.'s answer for a good solution to this.

Comment: Fine do to the opposition this may be more along what you are looking for.  http://andyonwpf.blogspot.com/2007/02/how-small-can-you-go-part-ii.html

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to create a new panel type, derived from `Panel` (or maybe `StackPanel`) which is called for example `IntegralClippingPanel`. In that panel's overrides of `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` make sure to only display child elements if they fit in their entirety inside the available space.